# paper-dialog, iron-overlay-canceled not fired

Tags: javascript, html, polymer-1.0

I have a `paper-dialog` with two `paper-button`, one for confirm and one for dismiss as following:

```
<!-- Change password dialog -->
<paper-dialog id="changePasswordDialog"
    on-iron-overlay-closed="_onDialogConfirm"
    on-iron-overlay-canceled="_onDialogCancel"           
    modal with-backdrop
    entry-animation="scale-up-animation"
    exit-animation="fade-out-animation">
    <h2>Enter your preferences</h2>
    <paper-dialog-scrollable>
       <!-- my content -->
    </paper-dialog-scrollable>
    <div class="buttons">
        <paper-button dialog-dismiss>Cancel</paper-button>
        <paper-button dialog-confirm>Change</paper-button>
    </div>
</paper-dialog>
```

And I have also the two events registered, closed and canceled as following:

```
_onDialogCancel: function(event){
    console.log(event);
},

_onDialogConfirm: function (closingReason) {
    console.log(closingReason);
},
```

If I press the `paper-button` *"dialog-confirm"* the event `_onDialogConfirm` is fired and the `closingReason.canceled = false`. If I press the `paper-button` *"dialog-dismiss"* the event `_onDialogCancel` is not fired and the event `_onDialogConfirm` is fired with `closingReason.canceled = true`.

**QUESTION**

Why only the `event on-iron-overlay-closed` is fired? I need to take a decision during `on-iron-overlay-canceled` and choose if I want to keep the dialog open or not but the event is never fired.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think this is how dialog-dismiss works, and it isn't supposed to fire an iron-overlay-canceled event (or did you read this somewhere?). can't you use the iron-overlay-closed event and use preventdefault somehow to prevent closing the overlay??